# Generating 'random' string from a different string in python?

Tags: python, string, random

I'm trying to generate a random string using the elements of a different string, with the same length.

Ex) String: AGAACGC

I want a random string using only elements from the string above

Right now I have:

```
import random
seq = 'AGAACGC'
length = len(seq)    

for blah in range(len(seq)): #Apologies for the lame variable names
    x = random.randint(0,length - 1)
    print seq[x]
```

And of course this will give me something like:

A

A

G

A

C

A

A

How would I alter the program so that it prints out my random string on one line?

I'm hoping for a relatively simple answer, as I'm still a beginner in python, so I don't want to get too fancy. But any help at all would be appreciated.

And is there a way to repeat the randomization 'n' number of times?

Say instead of 1 random string, I wanted 4 random strings on different lines. Is there an easy way doing this? (My newbish mind is telling me to repeat the loop 'n' times...but it needs to be a changeable number of randomized strings)

Sorry for asking. I'd really appreciate some help. I'm stuck on a bigger problem because I don't know how to do these steps.

Comment: Do you want it on one line with spaces in between, or without?

Comment: Without spaces please! Thanks

Comment: As a side note, when Python forces you to give a name to something that you don't care about, instead of naming it `blah`, the usual convention is to name it `_`. (Unless you're using `gettext` or similar i18n, which gives a special meaning for `_`, in which case your project probably has its own convention—maybe `__` or `dummy`—that you should follow.)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, there is a simple way to print a character without a newline, but in Python 2, there isn't.<sup>*</sup> So, the simplest way to do this is to build up the string, then print it at the end:

```
result = ''
for blah in range(len(seq)): #Apologies for the lame variable names
    x = random.randint(0,length - 1)
    result += seq[x]
print result
```

<sub>* There are two *less* simple ways: You can use `from __future__ import print_function` and then use Python 3 `print` syntax instead of Python 2, or you can use `sys.stdout.write(seq[x])` for each character and then `sys.stdout.write('\n')` and `sys.stdout.flush()` at the end. But I don't think you want either of those.</sub>

---

However, there are a number of ways to improve this:

- Use `randrange(length)` instead of `randint(0, length - 1)`.
- Use `random.choice(seq)` instead of using `randrange` or `randint` in the first place.
- Use `_` instead of `blah` for "don't care" variables.<sup>*</sup>
- If you don't care about what you're iterating over, just that you're iterating once for each character, just do `for _ in seq:`, not `for _ in range(len(seq)):`.
- Build up a *list* of letters, then call `''.join()` at the end, instead of building up a string.
- Use a comprehension instead of an explicit loop.

Putting that all together:

```
print ''.join(random.choice(seq) for _ in seq)
```

<sub>* Unless you're using `gettext` for i18n, or something else that gives `_` a special meaning. Most projects that do that come up with their own convention for "don't care" names—maybe `__`, or `dummy`. And of course `blah` would be fine for such a project, as long as you used it consistently.</sub>

---

As for repeating it, your newbish mind is right; just use a loop. For example (taking the second version, but it'll work just as well with the first):

```
n = 4
for _ in range(n):
    print ''.join(random.choice(seq) for _ in range(len(seq)))
```

That'll print out 4 different random strings. And if you set `n` to 100, it'll print 100 different random strings.

You may want to write this in a function:

```
def print_random_strings(seq, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        print ''.join(random.choice(seq) for _ in range(len(seq)))
```

And then you can call it like:

```
print_random_strings(seq, 4)
```

But either way, your basic intuition is right on track.

Comment: I don't understand the aversion to `__future__`'s `print_function`. Seems like we should be *encouraging* beginners to use the new features. +1, otherwise.

Comment: @jpmc26: Well, I'd much rather people just learned Python 3 in the first place. But if someone is learning 2.7, it's presumably because they're using a book, online tutorial, class, or whatever that's geared to Python 2, which means using Python 3 features is just going to confuse them in the early stages of learning, as none of the `print` statements their book/site/teacher gives them will work right and they'll have no idea why…

Comment: @jpmc26: Also, just telling people "Python 3 makes this easy, Python 2 doesn't" seems like the best way to nudge them toward thinking about why they're learning Python 2, without being too obtrusive about it. Of course they may not have a choice (e.g., there's a Python 2 class as a requirement for their degree, or they're learning it to work as a junior dev maintaining a system built in Python 2, or whatever…).

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on how I could use the loop for the first version (my newbie version of the random string). How could I add the 'for' loop (in your example you used "for _ in range(n):") to the first version? I'm not too great with nested loops.

Comment: Just kidding I got it.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what `random.sample` is meant for:

```
import random
seq = 'AGAACGC'

"".join(random.sample(seq, len(seq)))
# Gives you something like: 'CGAAACG'
```