# Python- How to repeat a loop for new result each time?

Tags: python

The program I needed to make reads a text file with 3 lines of aligned dna sequences(each with length 'n'), and prints out a random column for length 'n'.

[The alignment text](http://textuploader.com/xyh1)

If you don't want to click stuff, it's essentially this:

```
AGAACGC
AACCTAG
AGCTCAC
```

Here's my program:

```
import random

file = open('3seq.txt', 'r')

seq1 = file.readline().strip()
seq2 = file.readline().strip()
seq3 = file.readline().strip()

length = len(seq1)


rand1 = ''
rand2 = ''
rand3 = ''

for blah in range(length):
    x = random.randrange(length)
    rand1 += seq1[x]
    rand2 += seq2[x]
    rand3 += seq3[x]
print rand1
print rand2
print rand3
```

The result would be something like:

```
ACAGGAA
ATAAACA
ACAAGTA
```

I'm sorry if it's not too clear.

So the QUESTION is this:

How can I alter my program so that I get 'x' number of results? Say I wanted 3 results:

```
ACAGGAA
ATAAACA
ACAAGTA

AGCCCAA
CAGGGAC
CACCCAC

CGACGCA
TAAGATC
CAACGCC
```

I'm getting the answer I want...I just want more of it printed out.

Any help?

Comment: encapsulate your current script in a function and call it `3` times inside the loop.

Comment: Seems kind of similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932251/generating-random-string-from-a-different-string-in-python). Classmates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning up your code a little bit and creating a function for the specified work, it looks something like:

```
import random
sequence = open('3seq.txt', 'r')
seq1, seq2, seq3 = sequence.readlines()
sequence.close()

x = 3

def get_random(seq1, seq2, seq3):
    length = len(seq1)

    rand1 = ''
    rand2 = ''
    rand3 = ''

    for i in range(length):
        x = random.randrange(length)
        rand1 += seq1[x]
        rand2 += seq2[x]
        rand3 += seq3[x]
    print rand1
    print rand2
    print rand3
    print 

for j in xrange(x):  # 'x' being defined at the top.
    get_random(seq1, seq2, seq3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This cleared up how to use functions pretty well for me.

Comment: Well pretty glad to help you , you can also show appreciation by upvoting the answer and marking it with a green tick , if that really satisfied your problem. Thanks.

Comment: One more slight question. Is there a reason to use 'xrange' instead of 'range'? I interchanged them in my program and it still seems to work okay in either case.

Comment: Actually using `range` is completely fine, There is a slight difference in the speed, the `xrange` is a bit faster and efficient because it doesnot created the whole list as done by `range`.